# Addresses within radius of vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, intersection, spatial-query

I want a CSV file of all addresses that intersect with historical stream features.
Currently, I have 3 datasets ([see my blog](https://merglindev.wordpress.com/2017/07/13/stream-addresses-qgis/)) for this in QGIS 2.16.3 (MacOSX):

- a layer (.gdb) of historical stream data (blue)
- a layer (.shp) of address data (green)
- a layer (.shp) of
  property data (teal)
- an OSM layer (grey) for reference only

[image]
I assume I need a query that does the following:

```
Select all properties that intersect with vectors from stream-layer
then from the resulting properties 
select all addresses that intersect with those properties
```

Can this be done in a single Query (e.g. using ST_INTERSECT) or would I need something like PyQGIS to do this and would someone be able to help me with the syntax for that query/script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not bother writing a script for this goal. Unless you will have to repeat the process many times. The following is what I would do:

1. Spatial Query: Intersect the properties with the streams. Take care that your projections match.
2. Spatial Query: Select the addresses that are within a selected property. Again, check your projections.
3. Export the final selection as CSV

See also (from point 22)
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html

Comment: In the title you say 'radius', but in the question you only talk about a direct intersect. If you want to add a radius, you should first use the 'buffer' tool to create a radius.